# E mail Message system using Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, email, smtp, iis-8

I implemented a mail message system in asp.net using c#. It actually worked for small attachments like images. Then I tried to upload a file (more than 2mb and it is exe file) and I clicked the send button. That message didn't receive to my mail box and all other mails after that was also not delivered.

I am using IIS 8 with a local SMTP server.

How to solve this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the extension file from .exe to .ex1. That might be security issue that your SMTP doesn't allow to send an application type file (.exe)